# Live Transcribe & Notification offline languages

Tags: downloading, languages, accessibility, offline

I can not find it anywhere. Is **list of languages supported for download and offline transcribe** published somewhere?

When I check languages on my current old phone, none of them are shown as available for download.

It would be very helpful to use transcribe without an internet connection, but I don't want to risk buying a new smartphone with 6 GB RAM to find out I can't download my language.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

On Google Pixel 3a, **the languages that are available for download and offline use are:**

- English (Australia)
- English (United Kingdom)
- English (United States)
- French (France)
- German (Germany)
- Italian (Italy)
- Japanese (Japan)
- Spanish (Spain)

This is consistent with [the Play Store's listing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.audio.hearing.visualization.accessibility.scribe) as of an update on May 11, 2022.

> #### What's new
>
> • Transcribe offline in English, Japanese, German, Italian, Spanish and French. More to come.

However, as the question has mentioned, [offline use is only available on certain devices](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/9158064?hl=en#):

> ### Use Live Transcribe offline
>
> #### Download languages for offline use
>
> **Important:** You can download languages for offline use on Android devices with at least 6GB RAM and on all Pixel devices. Not all languages are available for offline use.

On Nexus 5 with only 2 GB RAM, languages are not available for download.